# Able to retrieve zipped values only once in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I created two lists in python 3.7.1, and zipped them using `zip`.

When I tried printing the result to the console, it worked the first time, but gave an empty list afterwards:

[image]
[image]

Why i am able to retrieve the values only once?

Comment: [Please do not post code as images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The zip function is actually just an iterator -- an iterator can only be traversed once. If you want to be able to iterate over it multiple times, convert it to a list first.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
c = list(zip(a, b))
```

Answer (score -1):

**Why is this?**

Because those are similar to generators, so you can print first time, but when you try to print it again, it starts from the end, and no values left, see an example (clearer than yours):

```
>>> l=[1,2,3,4]
>>> it=iter(l) # generator basically (as in your question, zip, is also considered as a geneartor here)
>>> list(it)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(it)
[]
>>>
```

**So how to solve this issue?**

Simply just replace this line:

```
zipped_list = zip(list1,list2)
```

With:

```
zipped_list = list(zip(list1,list2))
```

Then everything would work fine.